# Separating a joined file to original files in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I know that to append or join multiple files in Linux, we can use the command: `cat file1 >> file2`.
But I couldn't find any command to separate `file1` from `file2` after joining them. In other words, I want both original `file1` and `file2` back again. I tried to use the `split` command but it just dismembers a file into multiple files with the same size.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How would you know where to split them? Is there a string indicator or length of text, or number of lines?

Comment: If there's a context that identifies the end of the first file or the start of the second file, then `csplit` (context split) can help you.  Otherwise, you are stuck.  There's no information about the old states of the files maintained by the file system, so unless you know somehow where the original version of `file2` ended, there's no way to get back again.

Comment: It's just like joining 2 files and then separating them. So if cat command is not suitable, do you know any other commands?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command, since no information about what was file1 or file2 is retained. The new combined file is just a data stream.

In order to "split" them back up, you need rules about how to do so (such as, how many bytes file1 and file2 were).

Comment: Thanks.
But what do you mean by rules?

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the concatenation, the system doesn't keep track of how the resulting file was created. So it has no way of remembering where the original split was located in that file.
Can you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
So is there any command which appends file 1 to file 2 then is able to separate file 1 from file 2? What I'm trying to do is to append the hash signature to a plaintext file for securely transferring and then separate them for decryption.

Comment: Is your hash a fixed-length string, like MD5 being always 32 characters long ?

Comment: I heard about the head and tail commands. Do you guys here know about that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No problem, as long as you still have file1:

```
$ echo foobar >file1
$ echo blah >file2
$ cat file1 >> file2
$ truncate -s $(( $(stat -c '%s' file2) - $(stat -c '%s' file1) )) file2
$ cat file2
blah
```

Also, instead of `stat -c '%s' filename` you can use `wc -c filename | cut -f 1 -d ' '`, which is longer but more portable.